# Storing data into ArrayList through through servlets

Tags: java, servlets, arraylist

I am attempting to write an application that will make use of 3 different servlets.
One will display information, the other will allow users to enter data and display it, and the last servlet would allow users to edit existing data.
I am having trouble finding a way to store the data into an ArrayList from one servlet and displaying in a table on the servlet that displays the info.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/DisplayItems")
public class DisplayItems extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

public DisplayItems() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
    if (context.getAttribute("data_list") == null) {
        context.setAttribute("data_list", new ArrayList<String>());
    }

}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<String> list = (List<String>) getServletContext().getAttribute("data_list");
        list.add("1");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>Department Library</title>");
    //out.println("<style>h1,h2,form,p{text-align:center;color:white}body{background-color:black;}</style></head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>Welcome to the Department Library</h1>");
    out.println("<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'>");
    out.println("<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Type</th><th>Name</th><th>Addition Info</th><th>Available</th><th>Operation</th></tr><thead>");
    out.println("<tr><td>"+list.get(1)+"</td><td>"+list.get(0)+"</td><td>"+list.get(0)+"</td><td>"+list.get(0)+"</td><td>"+list.get(0)+"</td><td><a href='./EditItem'>Edit</a></td></tr>");
    out.println("<p><a href='./AddItem'>Add Item</a></p>");
    out.println("<p><a href='./EditItem'>Edit Item</a></p>");
    //out.println("<form method='post'><input id='inputtext' name='inputtext'></inputText><input type='submit' value='Translate' name='submit'></input></form>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
    out.close();

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

public  void row(String id, String type, String name, String info ){

}
}
```

AddItem

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Array;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/AddItem")
public class AddItem extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public AddItem() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>Add Items</title>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>Add Items</h1>");
    out.println("<form method='post'");
    //name=type
    //name=name
    //name=info
    //name=copies
    out.println("<table><tbody><tr><td>Type:</td><td><select name='type'><option>Book</option><option>Tablet</option> </select></td><tr>");
    out.println("<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input name='name' size='60'/></td></tr>");
    out.println("<tr><td>Additional Info:</td><td><input name='info' size='60' /></td></tr>");
    out.println("<tr><td># of Copies:</td><td><input name='copies' size='8' /></td></tr>");
    out.println("<tr><td colspan='2' rowspan='1'><input name='add' type='submit' value='Add' /></td></tr></tbody></table>");
    out.println("</form>");
    out.println("<p><a href='./DisplayItems'>Display Items</a></p>");
    //out.println("<p><a href='./EditItem'>Edit Item</a></p>");
    //out.println("<form method='post'><input id='inputtext' name='inputtext'></inputText><input type='submit' value='Translate' name='submit'></input></form>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
    out.close();    }

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    request.getParameter("type");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String info = request.getParameter("info");
    String copies = request.getParameter("copies");
    //type.add(value);

    out.println(name);
    out.println(info);
    out.println(copies);
}

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `hashmap` it would be much easier to get value from it. Also try to create a class of having all the parameter you need and create the object of that and pass it through `session` or `request` parameter.

Comment: When you get the data from one servlet you should persist it immediately or you fail in to pattern of loosing data.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : add the cast from `getAttribute()` to `List`

You could use store your `ArrayList` in a servlet context attribute to share it between all your servlets. But you should considere using a class to store data if it is more complex than a single String.

You could try to put something like that in init method of your servlets :

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
    if (context.getAttribute("data_list") == null) {
        context.setAttribute("data_list", new ArrayList<String>());
    }

}
```

and then in get or post methods, you simply access the shared list as :

```
List<String> list = (List<String>) getServletContext().getAttribute("data_list");
```

As suggested by Vighanesh Gursale you could also use a HashMap, if your data has a natural key.

Edit2 :

To be sure of what is happening, you should use the debugger to see what is null or add logs like following : one in each `init` method after creating the attribute

```
    if (context.getAttribute("data_list") == null) {
        context.setAttribute("data_list", new ArrayList<String>());
        log("Creating attribute data_list");
    }
    else {
        log("Attribute data_list already created");
    }
```

then in doGet :

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
log ((context == null) ? "Context null!?" : "Context ok");
Object attribute = context.getAttribute("data_list");
log((attribute == null) ? "Attribute null", attribute.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks. When i tried accessing the shared list it makes me have to add cast to it. then i try running it but it gives me error. Im trying to add from the form to the array list. By the way, I'm going to probably do hash map since i didn't think about that.

Comment: @user3162117 I initially forgot to cast and edited the post accordingly. But what is you new error ?

Comment: This is what i have `List<String> list = (List<String>) getServletContext().getAttribute("data_list");
  list.add("1");` and i get the error: javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
 hw1.DisplayItems.doGet(DisplayItems.java:35)

Comment: I did initialize exactly like you did. here is the error java.lang.NullPointerException
 javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
 hw1.DisplayItems.doGet(DisplayItems.java:34)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: @user3162117: you should debug or log to see what really happens. See my edited post.